# Is there a way to make a div work like an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

So I am building a website for a guy and he wants to take a page that I already made that is basically an order calculator and make it available on every page of the site in a pop-up div element. So I put together a simple iFrame that would load the page into its own box and everything would work properly, but he doesn't like the way it looks, and I admit, iFrames look a bit sloppy if they don't take up the whole page and they cause centering issues.

So I thought I would just put it into it's own div and just load the page via jQuery into the div, **but the problem arises with the stylesheets**. Both the location page and the loaded calculator page have essential CSS elements that they must use and they conflict with each other, so is there any way to make the css imports that are inside the div with the loaded page only apply to elements within that div without renaming everything?

Thanks for your help.

CODE:

```
function po()
{
    $("#calculator").load("/calculator/");
    $("#calculator").fadeIn();
    $("#modalbackground").fadeIn();
    $("#closeCalc").fadeIn();
}
```

Any other solutions would be gladly accepted!

Comment: There isn't a direct way to do this

Comment: Why does the iFrame look sloppy? What centering issues are you seeing?

Comment: If this is a full html page you're loading into a div you really should not do it that way. It breaks your code significantly.

Comment: Iframes can work just like any other element when you use CSS properly.

Comment: There's no other way, but there are ways to style the IFrame. Many sites use it, and it's very possible to style it so that you can not (or hardly) tell it's there.

Comment: There is no reason you shouldn't be able to use a iframe if page called in iframe is on same domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could put a border less iframe into a div

```
<div style='width:100px; height:100px;'>
    <iframe style='width:100%; height:100%; border:0;'></iframe>
</div>
```

The iframe should take the entire width of the div

Comment: I just `iframe { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }` etc - and keep the styles out of the HTML. Then, use the container to define it's size.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `frameborder="0"` to the `<iframe>` tag and it will look just like a scrollable `<div>`. You can even add your own border in CSS (although that's probably better done on a containing element rather than the `<iframe>` itself).

If you'd like, I can show you a screenshot from my website, which uses `<iframe>`s that look like `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading a whole page within a div, including the body tag, this is definitely wrong. You should instead load a page fragment (a specific div within your calculator page). In this case, just give this specific div a unique id and build your imported stylesheet based on this id to avoid conflicts:

```
#loginBox input {...}
```

If this is not possible, then I'd say that an iframe is the way to go. You can for example add a script within calculator that resizes its parent (accessed via parent.frameElement). For the record, html5 has a "seamless" attribute, but browser compatibility is still poor at this point.

Comment: It is a page fragment. I failed to mention that I removed all of those tags before I prepared the page to be loaded.

Comment: ok, and I see that you have an id loginBox. Then if you prefix all your styles with #loginBox there should be no conflict.

Answer (score 0):

To make the iframes work normally in Mozilla you need to use em as the unit instead of px or the normal % if it exceeds the div limit as in your case.

This question was asked on several FireFox forums but apparently they seem to have some security concerns over the use of iframes.

> The em value should be specified in the iframe tag and not in the div
>   tag

I have made a page which has three iframes one below the other (I know most people will not like it but I am a beginner) and they work perfectly fine across all browsers.

You need to be able to determine the em by practically trying it yourself.

I personally do not recommend the use of iframe as a work around but it should be used what it is designed for.

Hope this helps everyone reading my post. Please leave a comment if you think I am wrong. I would appreciate your help. Thank you!